# Hadoop job failing while in-merging files in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting the following error in the reduce step while merging/coping is happening:

```
java.io.IOException: Task: attempt_201306130308_0177_r_000002_0 - The reduce copier failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:211)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Intermediate merge failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.doInMemMerge(ReduceTask.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.run(ReduceTask.java:2628)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Rec# 13932: Failed to skip past record of length: 129
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$InMemoryReader.next(IFile.java:542)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$Segment.next(Merger.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.adjustPriorityQueue(Merger.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.next(Merger.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.writeFile(Merger.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$InMemFSMergeThread.doInMemMerge(ReduceTask.java:2687)
    ... 1 more
```

If, I look at the code in IFile.java at this location, it looks something like this:

```
long skipped = dataIn.skip(recordLength);
if (skipped != recordLength) {
     throw new IOException("Rec# " + recNo + ": Failed to skip past record of length: " + 
                             recordLength);
}
```

Basically, somehow the in-memory read of the next record is inconsistent. How is this possible? Is it because the buffer cannot completely fit in memory and I need to increase the memory?

Any suggestions what to try next?

Comment: What Writable do you use? If the Writable implementation has some error, the inconsistent may happen.

Comment: Like @zsxwing has commented - if you're using custom Writables in as your Key and / or Value type, then check the write and readFields methods - write a unit test that uses `ReflectionUtils.copy(src, dest)` and then some assertions that the two objects are identical (`ReflectionUtils` copies the object via serialization to a byte stream)

Comment: I am using Text as the writable for both key and values. The error happens sometimes. Any suggestions what I should try?